# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when looping over json object

Tags: python

I need to send a GET request to 1000 odd URLs, these URLs are fetched from a file. Response from these URL is converted to JSON object which I iterate and print values based on some key. This code works fine when executed on a single URL but it does not work within the loop.

I thought this is due to adding values to the already existing dict so I tried to delete the dict at the end of the loop but still the same problem

```
    import requests
    import objectpath
    import json
    user = ‘example_user’
    password = ‘example_pass’
    with open('rest.txt') as f:   #rest.txt contains all the URLs
        for url in f:
            r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
            data = r.json()
            jsonnn_tree = objectpath.Tree(data)
            result_name = tuple(jsonnn_tree.execute('$..name'))
            result_permission = tuple(jsonnn_tree.execute('$..permission'))
            print(result_name)
            print(result_permission)
    f.close()
```

I expect the O/P to contain the values corresponding to the key.

The error that I get is

```
data = r.json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 889, in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is `r.content` here? `HTTPResponse.json()` has a habit of erroring like this when the body of the response *can't be converted to JSON*.

Comment: You say "Response from these URL is converted to JSON", but the code says that you're expecting to get JSON back in response to your HTTP request and Requests will then turn that into a Python object.  So every URL in your list has to return JSON data, or this code is going to fail like you are showing us it is doing.  So do you expect all of your URLs to return JSON payloads?

Comment: Response from these URLs return JSON data which is converted to dict using "data = r.json()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL used in the get request was wrong because the output from variable url contained a new line character, I had to use url = url.rstrip('\n') to correct this problem. Issue is now resolved.

```
    import requests
    import objectpath
    import json
    user = ‘example_user’
    password = ‘example_pass’
    with open('rest.txt') as f:   #rest.txt contains all the URLs
    for url in f:
        url = url.rstrip('\n')
        r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
        data = r.json()
        jsonnn_tree = objectpath.Tree(data)
        result_name = tuple(jsonnn_tree.execute('$..name'))
        result_permission = tuple(jsonnn_tree.execute('$..permission'))
        print(result_name)
        print(result_permission)
    f.close()
```